# How do I pin a *file* on the Start Menu in XP?

Tags: windows-xp

At work I have two XP PCs. On one, I can click with the left mouse button and drag a file from Windows Explorer to the Start button, which pops up the Start menu. Then if I drag it to the "pinned" area at the top, I get a horizontal black bar "cursor" and I can drop the file there. It sticks, and I have a permanent short cut to that file.

This works with graphics files, Word docs, Remote Desktop connection files, anything. Whatever file I put there is opened in its default application when I click it.

On the new PC I got this does not work. When I drag the file to the Start menu the horizontal black bar "cursor" never appears, and I can only drop files *onto* the apps that already in the list, which will then try to open the file I drop. Not at all what I want. Works for applications but not files.

Does anyone know the black magic required to make it work as it does on the first PC? I've scoured the interwebs looking for it, but the few suggestions I found (adding mysterious registry keys) do not work.

It's working on one PC so I know it's possible. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

right click the start menu an select properties in it there should be a button that says customize click it, then scroll down until you see a check box that says "enable context menus and dragging and dropping" click that and you should be able to pin to the start menu now

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't work for me. I assume you meant to add "Choose the Advanced tab" after choosing Customize. There is an "Enable dragging and dropping" box, but that is checked on both machines. There is nothing specifically about context menu, but I'm guessing you were just answering off the top of your head and got the wording wrong. Anyway, that box is checked and it still doesn't work. :-(

Comment: this sounds like an odd error because the check box "dragging and dropping" is what controls this. have you tried unchecking it, clicking apply,then re-checking it and clicking apply to see if that works?(this method would fix the auto hide tool bar when it wouldn't auto hide for me)

Comment: OK apparently this is the setting that controls this. The reason it wasn't working was that the files I wanted to pin were on the network. I verified this by trying to pin network files on the "working" machine, and that didn't work either. I suppose this is Microsoft trying to be "helpful" again. Probably a security thing... Oy ve. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: no prob. just curious though, are the files you're trying to pin being shared(and your account has the proper permissions) or are you going through a network drive and trying to pin it directly from its location?

Comment: The files are not being shared. They live in my private area on the corporate network so no other users can even see them (except IT). I have (or should have!) full access/rights to them. So I wonder if for some reason MS just prevents you from pinning network files...? No idea. The particular files I wanted to pin (Remote Desktop files for a couple of servers I work on) I was able to simply move to my C: drive. So I'm just glad it's working now. Thanks again.